# How to run integration test for share dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I have used following codes to run a driver test on share dialog in flutter none of them worked
Can we test share dialog by share plugin?

```
await driver.waitFor(find.byTooltip('shareDialog'));
await driver.waitFor(find.bySemanticsLabel('shareDialog'));
```